# Why "Goodness is from the whole cause; evil is from any defect."?

Tags: reference-request, good-and-evil, mereology

Where does this aphorism originate? Why is it true?

> Goodness is from the whole cause; evil is from any defect.
> *Bonum est ex integra causa, malum ex quocumque defectu.*

I've seen some sources say Aristotle's [*Metaphysics* 6.4](https://isidore.co/aquinas/Metaphysics6.htm#4) or Dionysus, but I can't find it exactly in this form.

Comment: [This source](https://www3.nd.edu/~afreddos/summa-translation/Part%201-2/st1-2-ques19.pdf) claims that the quote appears almost verbatim in chap. 4 of *De Divinis Nominibus*. A similar sentiment is attributed [here](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/good-evil) to Abraham Ibn Ezra "[who] sees the whole world as good. From God, he states, comes only good. Evil is due to the defect of the object receiving higher influence."

Comment: Seems like Socrates

Comment: Each of the words good, defect, evil have in Greek dozens of differentiating counterparts and are all translated with a single word. The meanings are totally lost...

Comment: With this kind of translations there is NO point in analysing these texts.

Comment: For some references see also http://philosophisches-jahrbuch.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/PJ52_S366-367_Kesseling_Bonum-ex-integra-causa-malum-ex-quocumque-defectu-bei-Plutarch.pdf

Comment: This quote is related with "ακρασία" ( akrasia) and is related with Socrates view about this, see Kristian Berry's related question.